# PHP and Prolog communicating in Hebrew

Tags: php, swi-prolog, hebrew

I call SWI-Prolog from PHP,

```
system(~\swipl.exe -f filename.pl -g goal,halt);
```

and it works great except when I need to pass data in hebrew between them I get UNICODE.

I solved the problem by having PHP write to a text file, which Prolog reads, and then writes back the answer which PHP reads, etc.
This can be a problem when many users will write and read the same file.
Of course I could use sessions, but is there a way to make them speak hebrew?
I tried changing the encoding etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I need to pass data in hebrew ... I get UNICODE".  Unicode and Hebrew are entirely different. Hebrew is a language, unicode is a character set, which includes the characters needed for Hebrew. Do you mean that you get garbage, because of incorrect conversion of (some other encoding eg cp1255) to unicode.

Comment: Yes I meant I get garbage instead of hebrew characters.

Comment: We will need to see the code that causes this problem. Can you create a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In the .php file:
`$exe = "~\swipl.exe";
$file = "-f filename.pl";
$goal = "-g run, halt";
$cmd = "$exe $file $goal";
system($cmd);`

In filename.pl:
`run :-
   writeln('אבגדה').`

I get on the screen:
\u05D0\u05D1\u05D2\u05D3\u05D4

Using: XAMPP for Win v. 1.7.0 with PHP 5.2.8,
Firefox Portable v. 48.0,
SWI Prolog Portable v. 7.2.2